# SQL Get users with max occurrences in table

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following table `transactions`, which records the IDs of sellers and buyers who had a transaction, I would like to determine the user who was involved in the highest number of transactions and the number of transactions that user engaged in.

| seller_id | buyer_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2020-01-02 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-03 |
| 3 | 2 | 2020-02-16 |
| 4 | 2 | 2020-02-22 |
| 4 | 3 | 2020-03-05 |

The desired output is this:

| ID | n_trans |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

Because user 2 had a total of 3 transactions (1 as seller, 2 as buyer) and user 4 also had 3 transactions (2 as seller, 1 as buyer). It can be assumed that a user cannot be a buyer and seller in the same transaction, and that each buyer-seller combination is not duplicated.

What SQL query will get me this? I would not find any similar questions online. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot, aggregate, and use window functions:

```
select id, cnt
from (select id, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from ((select seller_id as id, date from t) union all
            (select buyer_id, date from t)
           ) i
      group by id
     ) i
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Didn't know why I didnt think of using union all :)